# HttpClient connection reusing with 4.3.x

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm trying to use HttpClient and am having trouble deciphering the meaning of [1.1.5. Ensuring release of low level resources](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e145).

Are these how *closing the content stream* and *closing the response* are interpreted?

**Closing the content stream:** (keeps the underlying connection alive)

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
try {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/");

    // do multiple times on the same connection
    for (...) {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            try {
                // do something useful
            } finally {
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);    // <-- ensures reuse
            }
        }
    }
} finally {
    httpclient.close();
}
```

**Closing the response:** (immediately shuts down and discards the connection)

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
try {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/");

    // do multiple times on different connections
    for (...) {
        ClosableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                // do something useful
            }
        } finally {
            response.close();    // <-- ensures reconnect
        }
    }
} finally {
    httpclient.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

entityUtils.consume closes the stream for you...

```
if (entity.isStreaming()) {
    final InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    if (instream != null) {
        instream.close();
    }
}
```

You just 'release' your client back to the pool...

Then, you should wrap your HttpClient in a runnable...

```
public void run() {
    handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, HttpConnection.DID_START));
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(YourConnectionMgr.getInstance())
            .addInterceptorLast(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
                public void process(
                    final HttpRequest request, 
                    final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException { 
                    }
                })
                .build();
 }  //end runnable
```

At the endof runnable, the client just gets released back to the ConnectionPool and you dont have to worry about resources or cleanup.

Use a manager that extends [PoolingClientConnectionManager](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html)

```
newInstance =  new MyConnectionManager(schemeRegistry);
     instance.setMaxTotal(15);
     instance.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(15);
     HttpHost localhost = new HttpHost("api.parse.com", 443);
     instance.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(localhost), 10);
```

Then at the end , i think you do need to shutdown the pool.

```
YourConnectionMgr.getInstance().shutdown();
YourConnectionMgr.reset();
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633072/how-do-i-upgrade-from-defaulthttpclient-to-httpclientbuilder-create-build/22644425#22644425)

Answer (score 1):

In general, once you're done with the entity you want to discard it so that system resources aren't tied up with objects that are no longer meaningful.  In my opinion, the only distinction here is use.  That chapter on fundamentals is basically describing that point.  However you implement it, make sure that you use resources only for as long as you need them.  The low level resource is the InputStream in the entity, the high level resource is the connection.  If you're implementing something that doesn't need to read the full InputStream in order to make a determination, for example, just terminate the response and the cleanup will be handled for you efficiently.